# amCharts: How to set font family in chart title?

Tags: amcharts

This is how you define a title in amCharts:

```
"titles": [{
    "text": "My Chart Title"
}, {
    "text": "My Chart Title  222",
    "bold": false
}]
```

However I cannot define font family (as Arial) as the Title class does not support this. Any idea how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First it is necessary to identify the right title.
For that you need to add [`addClassNames`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart#addClassNames) in your configuration.

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
    "addClassNames": true,
    "theme": "none"
});
```

Next you have to set an `id` for your title. `AmCharts` will create an additional class on the `DOM-Element` thats includes the specified `id`.

```
"titles": [{
        "text": "My Chart Title",
        "id": "main"
 }]
```

resulting class: `amcharts-title-main`

Now everything you have to do is changing the font family whenever the chart is drawn using `jQuery`:

```
$(".amcharts-title-main").css("font-family", "Arial");
```

Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pfg0a1no/).

Answer (score 1):

Supplement to the comment: [@gerric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4487044/gerric)
For add classes in 4 version you need:

```
import * as am4core from '@amcharts/amcharts4/core'
...
am4core.options.autoSetClassName = true
```

https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/options/
https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/chart-element-class-names-and-css/

For titles will be generated, classes by template: `${classNamePrefix}${id}`
P.S. classNamePrefix by default: 'amcharts-'